# window.event.srcElement.innerText restricts its text length to 255 chars, how to overcome

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

On `mouseover` event on HTML grid, the `window.event.srcElement.innerText` restricts its text length to `255` characters while the original text on the HTML grid could be more `255` characters for a column.

```
function onGridMouseOver() {
    gridOnMouseOver(window.event);
}
```

The basic intent of using this function is to display a tooltip, the tooltip restricts the length to `255` as the `window.event.srcElement.innerText` truncates the data in the first place.

Comment: please rephrase the question. it is hard to parse.

Comment: I think you cannot change the maximal length of the `title` attribute.